# Cloudera CDH on EC2

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, cloudera

I am an aws newbie, and I'm trying to run Hadoop on EC2 via Cloudera's AMI.  I installed the AMI, downloaded the cloudera-haddop-for-ec2-tools, and now I'm trying to configure

```
haddop-ec2-env.sh
```

It is asking for the following:

```
AWS_ACCOUNT_ID
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
EC2_KEYDIR
PRIVATE_KEY_PATH
```

when running:

```
./hadoop-ec2 launch-cluster my-cluster 10
```

i'm getting

```
AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
```

Firstly, I have the first 3 attributes for my own account.  This is a corporate account, and I received an email with the access key id and secret access key for my email.  Is it possible that my account doesn't have the proper permissions to do what is needed here.  Exactly why does this script need my credentials?  What does it need to do?

Secondly, where is the EC2 key dir?  I've uploaded my key.pem file that amazon created for me, and hard coded that into the PRIVATE_KEY_PATH and chmod 400 on the .pem file.  Is that the correct key that this script needs?

Any help is appreciated?

Sam

Comment: So tracking the hadoop-ec2 script lead to: the **ec2-describe-instances** bin is the one that's throwing the error

Comment: It appears that EC2_HOME, EC2 USER_ID, EC2_PRIVATE_KEY and EC2_CERT env variables all have to be set, which leads me to believe these tools are meant to be run from the client machine, rather than the server instance.  Although I still don't know where to get the EC2_CERT, or what EC2_HOME is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cloudera ec2 tools heavily rely on the amazon ec2 api tools.  Therefore, you must do the following:

1) Download amazon ec2 api tools from http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351

2) Download cloudera ec2 tools from http://cloudera-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/cloudera-for-hadoop-on-ec2-0.3.0.tar.gz

3) Set the following env variables **I am only giving Unix based examples**

```
export EC2_HOME=<path-to-tools-from-step-1>
export $PATH=$PATH:$EC2_HOME/bin
export $PATH=$PATH:<path-to-cloudera-ec2-tools>/bin
export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=<path-to-private-key.pem>
export EC2_CERT=<path-to-cert.pem>
```

4) In cloudera-ec2-tools/bin set the following variables

```
AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=<amazon-acct-id>
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<amazon-access-key>
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<amazon-secret-key>
EC2_KEYDIR=<dir-where-the-ec2-private-key-and-ec2-cert-are>
KEY_NAME=<name-of-ec2-private-key>
```

And then run

```
$ hadoop-ec2 launch-cluster my-hadoop-cluster 10
```

Which will create a hadoop cluster called "my-hadoop" with 10 nodes on multiple ec2 machines